# Loading HTML file into a DIV with menu links

Tags: javascript, html, loading, href

I am extremely stuck on what I know is a very simple problem for experts. I am a bit of a novice. I am creating menu links which load a HTML file into a DIV. However it keeps loading into another window. I am using the following code:

```
<a href="ifitting" 
onclick="document.
         getElementById('iftext').
         innerHTML = '<p>MYCONTENT</p>';"
>
LINKID
</a>
```

"ifitting" is the menu link located in the "Navigate" div id.

I need it to load into the 'iftex" div id.

Here is a link to the testing page:

http://www.infinitefashions.com/test1.html

Any feedback that can be provided would be much appreciated. I have been stuck on this for two days and have not found a working answer(that I understood how to overcome anyway;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems :

First your `href` shouldn't take you to "ifitting" which is another page, but to "#ifitting" for example, which would be a bookmark in the same page.
And then you shouldn't have a line break inside your js innerHTML.

This works :

```
<a href="#ifitting" onclick="document.getElementById('iftext').innerHTML = '&lt;p&gt;Client Consultation:&lt;br&gt;Process begins with discussing our customersâ€™ personal tastes and their needs with the designer. We assess the function of the garment and advise on suitable cloths from our library of patterns, linings and trims.&lt;/p&gt;';">Initial Fitting</a>
```

Notice the `href="#ifitting"` and the `<br>` inserted in the innerHTML.

Comment: Only thing is now as I add the rest of the links the second is not populating. Do I need to tell it to drop the first href and load the newer one? Ugh

Comment: You added a new line in your "innerHTML" again. Use the HTML new line "<br>" instead.
`<a href="#mcon" onclick="document.getElementById('iftext').innerHTML = '&lt;p&gt;Measurements &amp; Construction:<br>Once...`

Comment: Yes I just added all the other links and code. Can you tell me what Im missing here? I used the <br> after each but the others are not loading into the div :(

Comment: No you misunderstood me : The `<br>` has to be inside the onclick attribute, right after the title of your text. See my last comment, between Construction and Once : you cannot have a newline after "Measurements & Construction:" like you have now. I am speaking of the text you  want to add INSIDE the div.

Comment: I have placed the <br> where you suggest. 1) I would like each of the links on their on separate line in the "Navigate" div. 2) Still, when I click on the other links they do not replace the content of the 'iftex' div see link (http:///http://www.infinitefashions.com/test1.html)

Comment: See this fiddle there : [http://jsfiddle.net/rSJGe/](http://jsfiddle.net/rSJGe/)

You must not have any "newline" character inside your js. Example:  
`getElementById('iftext').innerHTML = 'a<br>b'`  <br/>
is OK and :
    `getElementById('iftext').innerHTML = 'a`      
    `b'`
isn't

Comment: that did it!! Interesting, thanks taking the time to help me through this. Still getting use to working with code :/

Comment: Final question. Can I just change onclick to onload to have the first href(#ifitting) populate when the page loads?

Comment: The easiest would be to edit your div directly in the source page :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but I think you need to add return false; at the end of your of onclick event.

`<a href="ifitting" onclick="document.getElementById('iftext').innerHTML = '<p>MYCONTENT</p>';return false;">LINKID</a>`

Haven't tested it though!

Comment: Thanks Damon, just tested still no go :(

Answer (score 1):

maybe useful:

```
$('#someElement').load("someHTML.html");
```

Comment: Thanks Sara, not sure where to place that can you elaborate and ill test?

Answer (score 0):

This works in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8SUy/3/).

It is basically Damon's answer, properly implemented in a function
instead of inline in an onclick.

You can get away with one onclick function for all the links if you make the function
find the id of the link that was clicked and then look up the text in a lookup table or
load it with jquery $.load.  That isn't done here. This only solved the simple case posted.

HTML

```
<a href="" id="iflink">Initial Fitting</a>
<p>Content will show up below here on link click:</p>
<div id="iftext"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Note: You'll need to load jQuery for this to work
var iftextHTML = '<p>Client Consultation: Process begins with discussing our customersâ€™ personal tastes and their needs with the designer. We assess the function of the garment and advise on suitable cloths from our library of patterns, linings and other crap </p>';

$(function(){
    $('#iflink').on('click',function(){
        $('#iftext').html(iftextHTML);
        return false; // stop link from taking you off the page
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! Working on figuring this out. Very close, see above.